# How to divide an absolute value of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to find a vector operation such that every positive element becomes 1 and negative element becomes -1 and 0 remains 0. The first idea come to my mind is to use the following code,

```
a=[0.0023 0 -0.0011];
b=a./abs(a);
```

However, this fails to keep the 0 element in the original vector, which gives an NaN instead. How to realize this in Matlab without using a for loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`sign`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) function:

```
b=sign(a)
```